# When solving Coulomb's Law, should the answer be always absolute or positive?

Tags: forces, electric-fields, coulombs-law

When solving Coulomb's Law, should the answer always be absolute or positive? or are there other things to consider?

Like for this, Should it be:

F = −3.80 ×10^11 N or F = 3.80 ×10^11 N

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force is an example of a vector quantity and, as such, requires two quantities to describe it: the size of the force (commonly referred to as the magnitude) and the direction it acts in. Consider two point charges $q_1, q_2$ separated by a distance $ r $ then the force $ {\bf F} $ on the charge $q_2$ due to the charge $q_1$ is given as
$$ {\bf F} = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{ q_1 q_2}{ r^2 } {\bf \hat{r}},$$ where ${\bf \hat{r}}$ is the direction from where $q_1$ is situated to where $q_2$ is.

If the charges have the same signs, then $ q_1 \times q_2$ is positive and the force takes the form $ {\bf F} = +$ve number multiplying the unit vector and the charges pushes each other apart.

If the two charges have opposite signs, then $ q_1 \times q_2$ is negative and the force takes the form $ {\bf F} =-+$ve number multiplying the unit vector. This means the charges pull each other together.

There can be some inconsistency in the literature whether you associate the negative number with the size of the force or the direction. Mathematicians, in particular, would argue that the  magnitude of the force is a positive number by definition,and  in this case the $-$ve sign is associated with the unit vector. Physicist's, however, often associate the negative number with the magnitude of the force and take it that a negative magnitude for a force means that the force acts in the opposite direction to that assumed.

Answer (score 1):

Negative means that the force is attractive. Positive means that the force is repulsive

Answer (score 1):

Here negative sign is representing both charge will attract wach other. Ifthe sign was positive then they would repel.

If you know the general case here, **positive and positive charges repel**. Even **negative and negative charges also repel**. The sign of force will be positive for them.

**Positive and negative charges are attracted to one another**. So their sign is negative. Positive charge moves toward negative one.

In some cases you might see $$\vec F_{ab}=-\vec F_{ab}$$ which is newton's third law. There was equal and opposite force (to satisfy the direction we used the negative sign here)